# decomposing distribution function of sum

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, joint-distribution

I am thinking about decomposing distribution function of sum of two random variables into sum of distribution function.

Let assume $Y_1\sim F_1$ and $Y_2 \sim F_2$ and $Y_2\in \mathbb{R}$ and $Y_1\in \mathbb{R}$ and two variables are continues.Then can we write the cumulative distribution function of $Y_1+Y_2$ as below?
$$
F_{Y_1+Y_2}(\alpha)= Pr(Y_1+Y_2<\alpha)= Pr(Y_1<\alpha-y_2|Y_2=y_2)Pr(Y_2=y_2)
$$

can you help me answer these question

- is the formula above true?
- do we need any assumption on distributions?
- how can I decompose the right hand side of above equation to sum of two variables?(I guess one way is introducing a dummy variables, $U$, and including that in conditions)

Thank you all.

Comment: When $Y_2$ has a continuous distribution, $\Pr(Y_2=y_2)=0$ for all $y_2$, which would lead to you conclude that $F_{Y_1+Y_2}$ is identically zero.

Comment: The short answer is No, the formula is not true, and _especially_ not so for _continuous_ random variables because $P(Y_2 = y_2) = 0$ for a continuous random variable. Think of, or read about, the _law of total probability_, apply it for the case of _discrete_ random variables, and then see if you can figure out the result for continuous random variables by _analogy_.

Comment: Thank you @whuber. what I mean is density function of $Y_2$ in $y_2$

Comment: Then your units are all wrong: the left hand side is a probability (which is unitless) but now the right hand size becomes a probability density (whose units are the reciprocal of those in which $Y_1+Y_2$ is expressed).  One way to fix it up is to integrate over $y_2$, which will give a standard formula for the CDF of the sum.

Comment: There is no $y_2$ on the lhs of $$F_{Y_1+Y_2}(\alpha)= Pr(Y_1+Y_2<\alpha)= Pr(Y_1<\alpha-y_2|Y_2=y_2)Pr(Y_2=y_2)$$ which should ring a warning bell... _Hint:_  get rid of this $y_2$ by an integral.